# DES implementation in C/C++/C#

Tags: c#, c++, c, encryption, des

I am looking for existing implementations of different types of DES in C/C++/C##. My running platform is Windows XP/Vista/7.

I am trying to write a C# program which will encrypt and decrypt using the DES algorithm. I need some implementations with which i can verify my code output to see if i did the things in right order. For the implementations the code along with the executable will be good however not a must.

Comment: You do know that DES is crap, right?

Comment: i know it is cracked and all. I am doing so for this learning purpose. Once done with DES i would be moving to AES. Thats why i said i would like to get some existing app which we know generate the right outputs so that i can know i am doing the stuff the right way.

Comment: Saying it's "cracked" is a bit of a misnomer - the only real problem with DES is its short keylength.  Encrypting multiple times with multiple keys - 3DES - fixes this problem, but also greatly slows the process down; 3DES is still thought to be completely secure, though.  That being said, AES offers the same amount of security, but is lightning fast and (nowadays) more widely available.  The only real reason to use 3DES anymore (aside from learning) is to interact with legacy systems.

Comment: @BlueRaja: The other downside of DES and 3DES is that it's still a 64 bit block size, which is not considered secure once you send on the order of 2^32 blocks without changing the key (which is quite feasible given modern network speeds and storage sizes).  Modern block ciphers use at least a 128 bit block size.

Comment: Someone care to explain the -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input.. I found these links where in I could calculate the DES values for giving input.

1. http://www.unsw.adfa.edu.au/~lpb/src/DEScalc/DEScalc.html
2. http://www.riscure.com/tech-corner/online-crypto-tools/des.html

Comment: All your linkes are dead.

Answer (score 2):

Nearly all open source C/C++ crypto libraries implement DES. You could for instance use OpenSSL, PolarSSL, LibTomCrypt, Crypto++, or any other library of your choosing for testing/experimentation.

In C# there seem to be fewer options, simply because the default .NET crypto libraries somewhat inhibit the desire for anyone else to compete in this space, but [BouncyCastle's C# code](http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp) (http://www.bouncycastle.org/csharp/index.html) does contain an implementation (in src/crypto/engines/DesEngine.cs).

Comment: Are there any weblinks where i can put in some text and see the encypted form and then decrypt the text as well.

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.des.aspx

Comment: The trouble with that is that (I think!) it's a wrapper on the native implementation and he won't be able to easily step through that and compare intermediate values if he's having trouble debugging his own code.